# compute the gradient in high dimension

Tags: numerics, vector-calculus

The following code is used to compute the gradient of a given 2D data.

```
computeGrad[data_] := Module[{D1, D2, grad, h = 1, xdim, ydim, n},
   D1 = Append[data[[2 ;; -1, ;;]], data[[-1, ;;]]];
   D2 = Prepend[data[[1 ;; -2, ;;]], data[[1, ;;]]];
   {xdim, ydim} = Dimensions[data];
   grad = ConstantArray[0, {xdim, ydim, 2}];
   (*central differences on X-axis*)
   grad[[;; , ;; , 1]] = (D1 - D2)/(2*h);
   grad[[1, ;; , 
     1]] = (4*data[[2, ;;]] - 3*data[[1, ;;]] - data[[3, ;;]])/(2*h);
   grad[[-1, ;; , 
     1]] = -(4*data[[-2, ;;]] - 3*data[[-1, ;;]] - data[[-3, ;;]])/(2*
       h);
   (*central differences on Y-axis*)
   D1 = Join[data[[;; , 2 ;; -1]], Transpose[{data[[;; , -1]]}], 2];
   D2 = Join[Transpose[{data[[;; , -1]]}], data[[;; , 1 ;; -2]], 2];
   grad[[;; , ;; , 2]] = (D1 - D2)/(2*h);
   grad[[;; , 1, 
      2]] = (4*data[[;; , 2]] - 3*data[[;; , 1]] - data[[;; , 3]])/(2*
       h);
   grad[[;; , -1, 
      2]] = -(4*data[[;; , -2]] - 3*data[[;; , -1]] - 
        data[[;; , -3]])/(2*h);
   n = ArrayDepth[grad];
   Map[Normalize, grad, {n - 1}] // N
   ];
```

For example:

```
data = Table[Sin[x]*Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}];
grad = computeGrad[data];
```

gives 
[image]
How to extend the code to deal with data higher than 2 dimensions? Is there any place to enhance the code to make it more efficient?

Comment: Use `ListInterpolation` + `Grad`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. The easiest, I think, is to use [`DerivativeFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DerivativeFilter.html):

```
data = Table[Sin[x]*Cos[y], {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}];

gradFilter[data_] := Module[{n = ArrayDepth[data]},
  MapThread[List, 
   Table[DerivativeFilter[data, UnitVector[n, i]], {i, n}], n]]

ListVectorPlot[gradFilter[data]]
```

[image: vectorplot]

I made this independent of dimensions by constructing the entries in the gradient from derivatives in the direction of each `UnitVector` in the range given by the value of `ArrayDepth` for the data.

`DerivativeFilter` uses interpolation of the data, and has an option for `InterpolationOrder`. But if you want to work without interpolation, there is an alternative way of computing gradients that uses finite difference methods, similar to what you programmed in the question.

The following function allows you to set the order of the finite-difference approximation (the number of points for the discrete derivative) explicitly, as a second argument `order`:

```
gradFilter[data_, order_] := 
 Module[{n = ArrayDepth[data]}, 
  MapThread[List, 
   Table[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[UnitVector[n, i], 
      Range /@ Dimensions[data], "DifferenceOrder" -> order][
     data], {i, n}], n]]
```

This uses the built-in functionality explained in the documentation for [The Numerical Method of Lines](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) to construct the derivative *operator* for each direction, and then applies it to the data.

Here is a comparison between the exact gradient and the one calculated with the second function, using derivative order `2`:

```
v[x_, y_, z_] := 
 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + .1] - 1/
  Sqrt[.1 + (x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2]

e[x_, y_, z_] = D[v[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}];

gradCompare = 
  Table[e[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, {z, -2, 2, .1}];

ListVectorPlot3D[gradCompare, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[#7] &)]
```

[image: original]

```
data = Table[
   v[x, y, z], {x, -2, 2, .1}, {y, -2, 2, .1}, {z, -2, 2, .1}];

gr2 = gradFilter[data, 2];

ListVectorPlot3D[gr2, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> (Hue[#7] &)]
```

[image: discrete]

So the second-order derivative approximation was sufficient to reproduce the gradient in this case. The first version of the `gradientFilter` without a specified order requires an additional interpolation run for each directional derivative, and therefore is noticeably slower than the implementation using `FiniteDifferenceDerivative` - I didn't show the plot for that result because it looks visually the same as the other ones.

Just remember that you have to specify the derivative order explicitly to invoke the faster version of the function.

Comment: `@Jens,Very general and comprehensive. I think the *2* in the first gradFilter function should be *n*. The code I provided is a little more efficient for 2 dimensional data though. :-)

Comment: For the first function I think the bottom two levels need to be transposed - at least, I need `Transpose[gradFilter[data], {1, 2, 4, 3}]` for it to work with `ListVectorPlot3D` and 3D `data`. For the second function, I think instead of `Partition[..., Length[data]]` you need `ArrayReshape[..., Append[Dimensions[data], n]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh sorry - I din't notice that. I'll double check and make the change. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @novice Thanks for the correction, I edited the answer to also include the comment by MichaelE2.

Comment: +1 on the thorough answer, particularly note on specifying order.

Comment: @Jens, for different units (e.g. distance and angle), I added If[
  i == angledim, Pi, 1] to the code
computeGrad[data_, order_: 2] := 
  Module[{n = ArrayDepth[data]}, 
   MapThread[List, 
    Table[If[i == angledim, Pi, 1]*
      NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[UnitVector[n, i], 
        Range /@ Dimensions[data], "DifferenceOrder" -> order][
       data], {i, n}], n]
   ];